# "setpci: command not found" in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, redhat

I'm trying to configure my Mac Mini running CentOS 5.5 to start automatically when power is restored after a power loss.  I understand the following command has to be executed:

```
setpci -s 0:1f.0 0xa4.b=0
```

When I run that command on my machine though I get `bash: setpci: command not found`.  Is there a package I need to install via `yum` or something?  I'm not seeing a clear answer via Google and I looked at the man page for setpci and it doesn't mention anything.

Also, does this command need to be run every time the machine starts or just once?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in my case is that I was connected to the server via SSH as a non-root user and when I executed `su` to run the `setpci` command I didn't not run `su` with the `-` modifier.  This caused my `root` users environment variables not to be included and caused the `setpci` command to fail.

Executing `su -` instead of `su` fixed my problem.